# What is happening when you deploy a BNA file to Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

After I've put together my business network definition, what is actually happening on peers after I deploy that package?  I'm especially interested in how a hyperledger peer can be interpreting javascript, since that doesn't appear to be a supported language for chaincode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Composer chain code is written in Go. It uses the Duktape Javascript interpreter to execute the user (and system) JS code within a Go process.

The Composer chain code maps the public JS API to the underlying Fabric Go API calls.

From a Fabric perspective this is just a "normal" piece of Go chain code, albeit quite a complex one!

When you "deploy" a business network using the Composer CLI, you are actually doing 2 things:

- deploying the Composer chain code (Go) and starting it
- deploying the bytes of the business network archive and storing it in world-state, so that it is available to the interpreter when you submit transactions

In the future we would like to replace the use of Duktape by native Node.js execution. Thanks to Fabric's modular architecture (and use of Docker containers and gRPC) this should be possible.

Comment: Is there a way to get/downoad/view the chaincode which is deployed to the fabric network via deploying a .bna file?